# How to add a new line to an excerpt?

Tags: excerpt

I am trying all day to add a new line to excerpts that I am using with my blog but I have not managed to do it yet!
I am using Canvas theme and Visual Composer.
I am trying to add manually these excerpts.
I've also tried to use this method (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151161/how-to-prevent-wordpress-from-stripping-html-tags-in-excerpt) but it doesn't work.
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "add a new line to excerpts"?  It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you display the excerpt using `the_excerpt()` function and the excerpt is manually created, line breaks and some HTML tags are allowed and will work perfectly. Can you show to us how are you printing the excerpt?

Comment: You can see directly from my blog (blog.devcanvas.org) the difference between the full posts and the excerpts.As you can see all new lines are stripped out from the excerpts.

Comment: Now I've erased all manual excerpts but the problem remains.

Comment: @skiabox You'll need to touch base with the support forum for the Canvas theme on this, I think. They're probably already making changes to the excerpt within the theme, and there's not much we can do for you here without knowing how that theme works.